# Thinkpad X200 Tablet for programming

Tags: laptop, tablet, development

I saw there are some posts about programming on netbooks, but not about tablets, who have a larger screen..
I want to buy a notebook (my first, actually), and a tablet would be the best choice: ultra-portable, pretty good for reading books, good for taking notes, diagrams.
The problem is the size of the display: I'm not sure if the resolution provided by the x200 (12.1") is adequate (1280x800, 16:10), and if the text is big enough (it has about 124 dpi). I'm more concerned about the high DPI than the resolution (most 15" laptops I saw had the same resolution and it was O.K. for me).
The keyboard seems to be the one used on the T series (full size), so this is definitely not a problem :)

Does anybody have this tablet (or something equivalent with a 12" screen, like the Dell XT or HP tm2) ? What do you think about programming on it?
Thanks in advance!

*PS: I work mostly in Visual Studio, Notepad++, Eclipse*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x200, tablet or standard laptop have incredible build quality and amazing keyboards.  These, from a purely physical standpoint, are an excellent choice for programming.  The screen resolution might be a bit low, but not horrible.  If I were you, I would wait until the next line of x200 machines come out later this month.  I've heard rumors 23 of Feb they will be announced.

The new one might have a higher resolution screen.  You are going to be paying for brand new technology, so it will most definitely be expensive.  The upside is, if you really want an older x200 tablet, they will most definitely come down in price after the new ones are released.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are the specs:
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo P8600 2.40 GHz (3MB L2 cache, 1066MHz FSB)
Chipset: Intel GM45/ICH9-ME
Memory: 2GB DDR2 667MHz (1x 2048MB) (can support up to 4GB of DDR3 Memory @ 800/1067MHz)
Hard Drive: 7200RPM 160GB SeaGate Momentus (ST9160823AS) SATA

Then I have written some large packages with much lower spec machines!
A second monitor is always nice.

But not really an SO topic